# clarification regarding pseudo-isomorphism and Iwasawa algebra

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am trying to understand Iwasawa theory and the concept of pseudo-isomorphism is not clear to me at all. I see three definitions:
Let $R$ be a ring (we typically take it to be $\mathbb Z_p[[T]]$). Let $M$ and $N$ be two $R$-modules.

1) $M$ and $N$ are said to be pseudo-isomorphic if there is a map between them with finite kernel and cokernel (finite as sets).

2) $M$ and $N$ are said to be pseudo-isomorphic if there is a map between them with kernel and cokernel both $R$ modules of finite length.

3) $M$ and $N$ are said to be pseudo-isomorphic if there is a map between them with kernel and cokernel are "pseudo-null", i.e., have annihilators of height at least two.

The first seems to be most natural way to extend the notion of isomorphism, but the second and third seem very unmotivated to me. Could someone point out why one makes a strange definition like the one in 3), and if it is related to the other two.